# du: combine both timestamps

Tags: disk-usage, timestamps, dump

On Linux, `du` offers the displaying of timestamps: `atime` OR `ctime` OR `mtime`

**Question:** Is there an easy way to get all three of them displayed at the same time (one file, all three timestamps)?

I guess to know how to solve this with `diff` (and possibly `cut`), but I'm rather looking for a single command to accomplish this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stat` command allows to get the specific data, restrict the output to the file attributes you want, and with user defined formatting. For example to get the time in full resolution:

```
$ stat -c $'%n:\n%x\n%y\n%z' file1 file2
file1:
2015-04-27 08:25:37.199806691 +0200
2015-04-27 08:25:37.199938422 +0200
2015-04-27 08:25:37.199938422 +0200
file2:
2015-04-27 22:05:54.739008929 +0200
2015-04-27 22:05:54.739091897 +0200
2015-04-27 22:05:54.748412643 +0200
```

Or more compact (`<Tab>` separated) with time information cropped to seconds:

```
$ stat -c $'%n:\t%.19x\t%.19y\t%.19z' file1 file2
file1:  2015-04-27 08:25:37 2015-04-27 08:25:37 2015-04-27 08:25:37
file2:  2015-04-27 22:05:54 2015-04-27 22:05:54 2015-04-27 22:05:54
```

Comment: (*thundering sound of facepalm*): `stat`! Of course! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `stat`:

```
$ stat file
  File: ‘file’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 10359339    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1001/  terdon)   Gid: ( 1001/  terdon)
Access: 2015-06-04 13:01:38.783306531 +0300
Modify: 2015-06-04 13:01:38.783306531 +0300
Change: 2015-06-04 13:01:38.783306531 +0300
 Birth: -
```